# How to avoid actual method call while running through junit test case

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have the following scenario.

A class `MyClass` in which I have an API `myAPI()` whose contents are as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    public void myAPI() {
        ...
        MyOtherClass myOtherObj = new MyOtherClass();
        String value = myOtherObj.decodeAndGetName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Here we have `MyOtherClass` which contains an API `decodeAndGetName()` which does some operation. It is in a different package and I can't modify its code.

**Requirement**

I need to write a junit test for the above `myAPI()`. Now I want to somehow mock the object of `MyOtherClass` and mock the return value of `decodeAndGetName()`.

I am not able to do this, as we have a `new MyOtherClass()` and as soon as the flow comes to this line, it creates a new instance and goes to the `decodeAndGetName()` API.
What I need is, some way to prevent the flow going to `decodeAndGetName()` and take a mock value instead when this call is encountered in the above code.

Please let me know a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used it with Android code, but I think you may be able to make use of something like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock the MyOtherClass in your tests with code similar to:

```
MyOtherClass mockMyOtherClass = Mockito.mock(MyOtherClass.class);
when(mockMyOtherClass.decodeAndGetName()).thenReturn(new String("known return value");
```

I would also suggest using dependency injection and make use of something like [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) in order to accomplish this.  I use the combination of Guice & Mockito on a daily basis with my Android projects to successfully accomplish exactly this sort of thing.

**Brief Example**
Here is what your code may look like after setting up dependency injection with Guice:

MyOtherClassWrapper.java

```
@Singleton
public class MyOtherClassWrapper {

    private MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();

    public String decodeAndGetName() {
        return getMyOtherClass().decodeAndGetName();
    }

    ...

    private MyOtherClass getMyOtherClass() {
        return myOtherClass;
    }

}
```

---

MyClass.java

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    @Inject private MyOtherClassWrapper myOtherClassWrapper;

    ...

    public void myAPI() {
    ...
    String value = getMyOtherClassWrapper().decodeAndGetName();
    ...
    }

    private MyOtherClass getMyOtherClassWrapper() {
        return myOtherClassWrapper;
    }
}
```

Please see the [Guice User's Guide](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted) for info on how to get started setting up Guice.  It's not too difficult.

Comment: I had tried something similar to what you suggested above, but using EasyMock - "EasyMock.expect(mockMyOtherClass.decodeAndGetName()).andReturn("abc");" but this does not seem to be working. Can you give me an example of how we can do it using Guice alongwith the Mock.

Comment: You can have a look at the [Guice user guide Getting Started page](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted) they show how to get started using Guice for dependency injection.  It sounds like you will probably need to wrap `MyOtherClass` in a `@Singleton` class to provide access to the methods you need.  You would then `@Inject` your wrapper class wherever you need access to the `MyOtherClass` methods and change instantiations of `MyOtherClass` to references to the `@Inject`ed instance of the `MyOtherClass` wrapper class.

Comment: Added basic example code.  You'll still need to see the Guice user's guide for Guice setup.